# CSS card flip effect - how to make it flip in the same direction with every click?

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a css animation that flips a card on click. I've followed the [answer posted in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38262021/1193304), but I'd like to know if there's a way to perform the same animation when the class is added and removed.

[In this case](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/rsg59hbL/) the card flips in one direction when clicked, and in the opposite direction when clicked again (as the css class is toggled). How could I make it so that the card flips in the same direction every time it is clicked?

Some code from the JSFiddle:

```
$('.flip-container .flipper').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.flip-container').toggleClass('hover');
    $(this).css('transform, rotateY(180deg)');
});

/* flip the pane when hovered */

.flip-container.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}


/* flip speed */

.flipper {
    transition: 0.8s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}


/* hide back of pane during swap */

.front,
.back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}


/* front pane, placed above back */

.front {
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}


/* back, initially hidden pane */

.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background-color: #fff;
}

.artist-1 {
    background: url(http://img.bleacherreport.net/img/images/photos/003/556/940/edab30087cea36c0ca206fc61a4b10fa_crop_north.jpg?w=630&h=420&q=75) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: How can you say which way the card flips? It's purely up to observer, one can say clockwise, other counterclockwise. You would have to add some perspective and make border edges smaller or bigger - only than you can be sure which ways it rotates.

Comment: By changing `rotateY(180deg)` to `rotateY(-180deg)` we can change the way it flips. My question is how to perform the same rotation each time the card is clicked.

Comment: But you're right. In my code I have `perspective: 1000px` and I can see the direction it flips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be done via script (check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842891/css-transform-rotate-in-the-same-direction-each-time/29843413)). So by editing the example you followed, we can do it this way:

```js
$('.flip-container').each(function(i) {
    var thisFlipper = $(this).find('.flipper');
    var rotate = 0;
    thisFlipper.on('click', function(e) {
        rotate += 180;
        thisFlipper.css({'transform': 'rotateY('+rotate+'deg)'});
    });
});
```

```css
.flip-container {
    perspective: 800px;
}

.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}

/* flip speed */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.8s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front,
.back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */

.back {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.artist-1 {
    background: url(http://img.bleacherreport.net/img/images/photos/003/556/940/edab30087cea36c0ca206fc61a4b10fa_crop_north.jpg?w=630&h=420&q=75) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front artist-1">
            
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <p>You won</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/csvp9u01/)

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. And I guess this is a duplicate question... I didn't see that other one you posted.