# Having an issue with adding a flipping card effect to an existing container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to learn HTML, CSS and Javascript for my personal website and I want it to be as simple as possible, using only their purest forms so I don't get lost in anything too deep.

I used Webflow to properly align the contents of my website, and made some final edits to better suit my needs. I wanted to achieve the effect of flipping a business card, but all my attempts failed, likely because I don't know how to implement that effect to preexisting elements. I originally thought that it would be as simple as adding the properties that I need to classes and then have the `div` elements inherit from multiple places, provided they don't override one another.

However, I've come to realize that it's somehow not as simple as that when it comes to CSS and HTML. I went by other examples, namely [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69460461/css-card-flip-effect-how-to-make-it-flip-in-the-same-direction-with-every-clic) and the whole card effect and the inner elements were... not as desired.

When I try to apply the styling as presented in the other answer, the background disappears and I can't click on anything to flip the thing.

I would like it to flip like the card in the aforementioned example, but any arrangement I put the divs in cases these problems.

The details of the code can be found in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mg74dafb/) here. Am I missing something? I've been trying my hand at HTML and CSS for about a week, but apart from the basic stuff, I'm as good as lost.

Comment: So, in summary it is not clear what do you want?

Comment: Do you want your card to flip after click?

Comment: Yes, apologies for the lack of information, I was rather frustrated when I posted this. I do want it to flip on a click, but any arrangement I put the div classes in turns it into a mess without a background.